# I cannot insert text directly into bookmark via VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

'Trying to insert text directly into a bookmark via VBA

'tried lots of things, but nothing worked.

'Can someone point out where I am getting this wrong?

```
Sub AddBookMark()

Dim BMName As String
Dim Contents As String

sText = "BM1"
Contents = "Testing"

With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
 .Add Range.Text:=Contents
 .Add Name:=BMName
 .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
 .ShowHidden = False
End With
End Sub
```

'Compile error: syntax error

Comment: What is `Range.Text:=Contents`? [`Bookmarks.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.bookmarks.add) has a `Range` parameter.

Comment: There is more information in the error message than what you've provided. Please [edit] your post to include the complete, full, exact error message and indicate the line on which it is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a bookmark to text that doesn't exist already in a document. In other words, you have to first select the text you want to enclose within a bookmark. If the text doesn't exist, then you must insert the text and then you can select it and finally insert the necessary bookmark to surround it.

If you had opened the VBE, Visual Basic Editor, and looked at your code you would see the statement `Add Range.Text:=Contents` in red and it was causing the syntax error because there are no such properties in the Bookmarks.Add method.

Even with the Bookmarks.Add method corrected your code would still fail because the string variable BMName is never given a value and the BookMark name cannot be blank.

Below is revise code of your routine that you should study:

```
Sub AddBookMarkRevised()

Dim BMName As String
Dim Contents As String
Dim rng As Range

BMName = "BM1"
Contents = "Testing"

Set rng = Selection.Range
rng.Text = Contents

With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
 .Add BMName, rng
 .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
 .ShowHidden = False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much taking the time to answer my question so thoroughly. Both your explanation and the revised code was helpful.